# Can we access nets hierarchically in system Verilog?

Tags: system-verilog

In the paper https://www.doulos.com/downloads/events/DVCon_08_abstractBFM_final.pdf Page3 Figure 1 the authors show system verilog package accessing net hierarchically.

```
package stimulus_pkg;
 class Stimgen;
  task run();
    repeat(10) begin
      #5 testbench_Top.R = 1'b0;
      #5 testbench_Top.R = 1'b1;
    end
  endtask
 endclass
 endpackage
```

I tried this in EDAPlayground and the code failed as I expected. Is there something that I am missing? Or could it be a typo?

https://www.edaplayground.com/x/2Da2

Answer (score 0):

I was the co-author of that paper. I believe the example was intended to show what you would likely want to do at first glance, and why it would you eventually not want it to work. I don't believe hierarchical references were ever allowed from a package.